# Reading contacts giving Force Close Error

Tags: android, android-contacts

I Have Tried Below tutorial For **Reading Contacts In Android**

```
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/read-contacts-from-device/

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/readContacts.html
```

Both Are Complete without any Error But When I Am Running It's Showing Force Close Error

I tried with API 8,13,16

Same Error For all. I Dont Know More About It But I Completly Follow Tutorial.

**Catlog Here**

```
09-30 14:02:09.121: D/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
09-30 14:02:09.121: W/dalvikvm(305): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.ReadContacts/com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.app.ReadContacts-2.apk]
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.app.ReadContacts-2.apk]
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
09-30 14:02:09.141: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  ... 11 more
09-30 14:07:09.262: I/Process(305): Sending signal. PID: 305 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the error in the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts Activity to your AndroidManifest.xml?

The error you're receiving suggests that you haven't...

The line to add is probably

```
<activity android:name=".ReadContacts"/>
```

although depending on your project structure it can be necessary to use the fully qualified name

```
<activity android:name="com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts"/>
```

Comment: `09-30 14:23:31.491: E/AndroidRuntime(424): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ‘1’: , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE (in_visible_group = ‘1’) ORDER BY display_name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC`
Now Giving This Error

Comment: That looks like to me we've solved the problem loading the activity and discovered another problem. If you're happy to mark this as answer that'd be great. If you want to post another question with the database code in the ReadContacts activity I'll keep an eye out.

Answer (score 0):

have u mentioned read contacts permission in manifest file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

if yes, post the error message from log cat

Comment: then post your log cat here, it will help in finding the error

Comment: **In Eclipse IDE go to 

Window>Show View>Others>Log Cat**

So when the application will crash you will the details regarding the error

Comment: The method managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String) from the type Activity is deprecated
I Think Its Error of this its coming when using 16 API
Now When M Setting API 8 or 10 Giving R Can not be Resolve
And When Using 16 Giving deprecated error

Comment: I Edit Question And Posted Log Cat

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the class `com.app.ReadContacts.ReadContacts` cannot be found. Have you specified your Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?